# CMakeLists.txt cross-referencing each other

Tags: cmake, circular-dependency

I am trying to migrate a project from a custom build script to cmake. The source structure looks roughly like this:

```
src
 |
 +-CMakeLists.txt
 |
 +-generated
 |  |
 |  +-CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 |  +-database
 |  |
 |  +-...
 |
 +-main
    |
    +-CMakeLists.txt
    |
    +-database
    |
    +-...
```

The source files in `generated/database` get autogenerated. `cmake` seems to be capable of this (that's not part of the question), but I wonder how I can make it build stuff in the right order. `main/database` contains the framework that is used in the autogenerated files. However, there are other folders in `main` that depend on the generated sources. If I structure the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
add_subdirectory("generated")
add_subdirectory("main")
```

I cannot refer to `main/database` in `generated/CMakeLists.txt` as dependency.

Overall, I have the impression that `cmake` forces me to structure my files according to their dependencies, but I want to preserve the current layout - the dependencies in the project are far too complex to map them onto a file system hierarchy.

Should I just avoid `add_subdirectory` and write everything in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`? It seems like this should be possible. Or is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Overall, I have the impression that cmake forces me to structure
my files according to their dependencies
```

If CMake has information that target A depends on target B (for example
`target_link_libraries(A B)`) B will be build first, then A.
If you use generated sources CMake can't get dependency information
and you need to provide it using [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies).

From documentation:

```
Adding dependencies with this command can be used to make sure one target
is built before another target.
```

Comment: In other words, the order in the CMake files shouldn't matter.  CMake will figure out the right order based on the dependencies of each target.  Just specify them carefully.